Use Symfonys MapRequestPayload to deserialize array of int
The payload for an API endpoint in my application is an array of numbers. Is it possible to deserialize it using MapRequestPayload?
What I tried so far isn't obviously working, since the deserializer used by MapRequestPayload gets its target type from the parameter type (which cant be something like int[]):
...
public function endpoint(
  #[MapRequestPayload] array $listOfIds
) {
...

